How to make \fpset behave like \FPeval
fp package provide function \FPeval . if I use \FPeval\aa{pi/2},then I can use \aa directly. the following code defined \fpset command , unlike \FPeval, the result has to be called with \fpuse. How to make \fpset behave like \FPeval ?
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fpset}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:N #1
  \fp_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpuse}{m}{\fp_use:N #1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fpset\aa{pi/2} 
\fpuse{\aa}  % can I use \aa directly instead of \fpuse{\aa} ?

\end{document}


\usepackage{fp}\let\fpset\FPeval

You can define how you want 'set' to behave: here I am storing the value in an internal fp which is then accessible using \aa:
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fpset}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l__XCN_ \token_to_str:N #1 _fp }
  \fp_set:cn { l__XCN_ \token_to_str:N #1 _fp } {#2}
  \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand #1 { }
    { \fp_use:c { l__XCN_ \token_to_str:N #1 _fp } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fpset\aa{pi/2} 
\aa

\end{document}


What to do when the OP's coauthor is called Ångström?

@egreg :) :) :)

@JosephWright   could you please make precision to be an optional argument in you code.  just like  this command : \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ro}{O{2} m}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}   if I type \fpset\aa{pi/2}   the output will be round to 2 decimal places by default.  if I type \fpset\aa[4]{pi/2}   the output will be round to 4 decimal places .

@XCN That wasn't in the question :) More seriously, as you know how to modify the result, I'm not sure what an edit offers here

@JosephWright  something like this \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fpset}{mO{2}m}
{
\fp_zero_new:c { l__XCN_ \token_to_str:N #1 fp }
\fp_set:cn { l__XCN \token_to_str:N #1 fp } {round(#3,#2)}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand #1 { }
{ \fp_use:c { l__XCN \token_to_str:N #1 _fp } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff    \fpset\zz[4]{pi}  %  round to 4 decimal places

You seem to be very stubborn in ignoring that fp and l3fp work in a very different way. And also in disregarding advice about careless usage of \def.
Don't use \def unless you precisely know what you're doing.
This said, your proposed
\def\aa{\fpeval{pi/2}}

is as wrong as it can be, because you're not storing the value, but the instructions to produce it. It might be
\edef\aa{\fpeval{pi/2}}

(but you shouldn't carelessly use \edef, of course).
I'll repeat my suggestion on how to do this.
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definefpvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
  \fp_set:cn { l_xcn_var_#1_fp } {#2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfpvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_if_exist:cTF { l_xcn_var_#1_fp } 
   {% the variable exists, set it
    \fp_set:cn { l_xcn_var_#1_fp } {#2}
   }
   {% the variable doesn't exist, error
    \ERROR
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

If you find that \usefpvar is inconvenient, add
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}

Full example:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definefpvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
  \fp_set:cn { l_xcn_var_#1_fp } {#2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfpvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_if_exist:cTF { l_xcn_var_#1_fp } 
   {% the variable exists, set it
    \fp_set:cn { l_xcn_var_#1_fp } {#2}
   }
   {% the variable doesn't exist, error
    \ERROR
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
 }

\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definefpvar{aa}{pi/2}
\definefpvar{xcn}{sin(\usefpvar{aa})}

\begin{document}

\texttt{aa} is \usefpvar{aa}

\texttt{xcn} is \usefpvar{xcn}

\texttt{aa} is \?{aa}

\texttt{xcn} is \?{xcn}

An approximation of \texttt{aa} is \fpeval{round(\?{aa},3)}

\end{document}


Is there any advantage in using \aa instead of \usefpvar{aa}? None that I can see, except if you

want to obfuscate your code;
want to risk clobbering defined macros.


thanks for your valuable advice. I would avoid that from this time on.
